# AnimatedImageVector missing in Jetpack Compose RC01

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose

`AnimatedImageVector` is no more present in Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-rc01
Also function `animatedVectorResource` is missing.

How to replace them?

Comment: It is so annoying to google where to find the required class. This question is still valid. They should update their docs while releasing new updates even minor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can read in the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.0.0-rc01):

[image]

> AnimatedImageVector was temporarily removed in order to change the module structure

**UPDATE:**
Starting from `1.1.0-alpha01`, "AnimatedImageVector and the related APIs are now in the new
`androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics` module. More detail in this [commit](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1753821).

```
    val image = animatedVectorResource(drawableId)
    var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Image(
        painter = image.painterFor(atEnd),
        contentDescription = "Your content description",
        modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp).clickable {
            atEnd = !atEnd
        }
    )
```